# UIButton in firstViewController does not change image properly when closing SecondViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, viewdidload

I'm saving image from SecondView Controller and resizing it.
Then when I go back to Firstview Controller the Button image on this Controller has to 
be loaded from just saved image file.

And image appears partly (only top part of image). But if I go to SecondViewController again and do not save image again and go back to First ViewController, the Button image appears completely and looks good.

```
- (void)showImageFirst { 

    //Show thumb image in button.

    NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
    NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/thumbtest.png", docDirectory];
    UIImage *tempimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    [imageForButton setImage:tempimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

and I call it in ViewDiDLoad and I also tried to put it in ViewDidAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear {
    [self.showImageFirst];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the first view controller a delegate of the second.

Then instead of saving the image to disk and then loading it back from the disk just pass the UIImage from the second view controller back to the first view controller.

I haven't checked but I'm almost certain that saving images to disk runs asynchronously so there is a chance that the image hasn't been saved when you are trying to load it again.

Comment: Thanks alot!  good idea! i did 2 actions in 1  (saved and delegate when view segued) and id did not work! ) now it`s ok! ))

Comment: Nice :) love it when you get something working elegantly and you can do more with less code.